# Objective C and ARC: Object produced in one thread does not get released in the consuming thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, nsdata

I have a small project that reads an HTTP stream from a remote server, demuxes it, extracts audio stream, decodes it into 16-bit PCM, and feeds into a corresponding AudioQueue. The decoder/demuxer/fetcher runs in a separate thread and it uses my home-grown blocking queue (see code below) to deliver the decoded frames to the AudioQueue callback. The queue uses NSMutableArray to store objects.

Once this thing is in-flight, it leaks objects inserted into the queue. Memory profiler says that the RefCt is 2 by the time I expect it to be 0 and to be released by ARC.

Here are the queue/dequeue methods:

```
- (id) dequeue {
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(objectsReady, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    [lock lock];
    id anObject = [queue objectAtIndex:0];
    [queue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [lock unlock];
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(freeSlots);

    return anObject;
}

- (void) enqueue:(id)element {
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(freeSlots, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    [lock lock];
    [queue addObject:element];
    [lock unlock];
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(objectsReady);
}
```

Producer thread does this:

```
[pAudioFrameQueue enqueue:[self convertAVFrameAudioToPcm:audioFrame]];
```

And the "convertAVFrameAudioToPcm" methods looks like this:

```
- (NSData*) convertAVFrameAudioToPcm:(AVFrame*)frame {
    NSData* ret = nil;
    int16_t* outputBuffer = malloc(outputByteLen);
    // decode into outputBuffer and other stuff
    ret = [NSData dataWithBytes:outputBuffer length:outputByteLen];
    free(outputBuffer);

    return ret;
}
```

Consumer does this:

```
- (void) fillAvailableAppleAudioBuffer:(AudioQueueBufferRef)bufferToFill {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSData* nextAudioBuffer = [pAudioFrameQueue dequeue];
        if (nextAudioBuffer != nil) {
            [nextAudioBuffer getBytes:bufferToFill->mAudioData]; // I know this is not safe
            bufferToFill->mAudioDataByteSize = nextAudioBuffer.length;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"ERR: End of stream...");
        }
    }
}
```

To me it looks like RefCt should become 0 when fillAvailableAppleAudioBuffer exits, but apparently ARC disagrees and does not release the object.

Am I having a bug in my simple queue code?

Or do I instantiate NSData in a wrong way?

Or am I missing some special rule of how ARC works between threads? By the way, the producer threads starts like this:

```
- (BOOL) startFrameFetcher {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                             (unsigned long)NULL),
                   ^(void) {
                       [self frameFetcherThread];
                    });
    return YES;
}
```

Any hints will be much appreciated!

PS: and last but not the least, I do have another instance of the same blocking queue that stores video frames that I dequeue and show via NSTimer. Video frames do not leak! I am guessing this may have something to do with threading. Otherwise, I would have expected to see the leak in both queues.

Comment: are you making sure to enter an @autoreleasepool scope periodically? each time through your loop? if you don't, the autorelease pool normally drains after each event loop callout.

Comment: also, you could try building with "analyze" and see if you get any retain cycle warnings or anything like that.

Comment: Does `-frameFetcherThread` loop indefinitely (or at least for a good long while)? You should not be abusing a GCD thread as if it were a normal thread. Instead you should be creating a new thread with `NSThread` and running `-frameFetcherThread` there.

Comment: blocks retain objects brought from out of scope

Comment: Many thanks for the quick and useful answers! Based on your suggestions I did two things. First, I put autoreleasepool inside of the semi-infinite loop of the producer. Second, I changed GCD thread to an NSThread. The end result - memory leak is gone! Decoded audio buffers are released promptly. Now, my question is the cost of atoreleasepool inside of the loop. How expensive is it?