# GCD dispatch_semaphore in non-GCD environment

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

I have an Objective-C application the uses one explicit background thread that is spawned via [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector]. This background thread is an HTTP stream demux that produces video and audio frames and puts them in two dedicated object queues. These queues are identical with the exception of the initial size. They use an NSLock and a pair of dispatch_semaphores to implement a blocking queue. This is how the main 5 operations are implemented:

```
- (id) init:(uint)queueSize {
    queue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:queueSize];
    freeSlots = dispatch_semaphore_create(queueSize);
    objectsReady = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    lock = [[NSLock alloc] init];

    return [super init];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"BlockingQ is being destroyed");
}

- (id) dequeue {
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(objectsReady, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    [lock lock];
    id anObject = [queue objectAtIndex:0];
    [queue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [lock unlock];
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(freeSlots);

    return anObject;
}

- (void) enqueue:(id)element {
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(freeSlots, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    [lock lock];
    [queue addObject:element];
    [lock unlock];
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(objectsReady);
}

- (uint) count {
    [lock lock];
    uint ret = [queue count];
    [lock unlock];
    return ret;
}
```

When the times come to stop the playback, I notify the background thread that it need to stop and then I wait for it to terminate. Once this is done, I attempt to clean up the queue 
by doing something like this:

```
- (void) clear {
    [lock lock];
    [queue removeAllObjects];
    while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(objectsReady, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW) == 0)
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(freeSlots);
    [lock unlock];
}
```

The purpose of the while-loop is to "balance" wait/signal calls and to ensure that both semaphores are released when their value equals to their initial value. I picked it up from reading this discussion: [Why does this code cause "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287621/why-does-this-code-cause-exc-bad-instruction/8288982#8288982)

However, even this loop does not save me from a crash when one of the queues is destroyed. The debugger shows a fragment of assembly code that is almost identical to what is shown in the link above.

So, my questions are:

1. Is it legitimate to mix GCD semaphores with NSThreads?
2. How do I ensure that the semaphores are in a good state to be destroyed?

Many thanks!

Comment: I suspect you'll not see a lot of traction on this question because you are mixing concurrency models (hand rolled threading w/GCD semaphores).   As well, there is some weirdness with that code (the `init:` method's implementation, for example) that indicates that it is pretty far afield of the norm of patterns.  It also isn't clear why any of this requires a hand rolled threading model vs. simply using GCD and some throttling mechanism (potentially semaphores).

Comment: Thank you for your response, @bbum. The reason for using hand-rolled threading is that my background is primarily C++ on POSIX systems. I tried to use the knowledge that I already have and the concepts available in Apple middleware but due to the lack of expertise in the latter, I apparently misused it. Apart from learning more about GCD in a short period of time and fully embracing it, what do you think my options are? Should I try re-writing this using POSIX semaphores? Or maybe there is a pre-canned generic blocking queue implementation in iOS that I don't know about? Thanks again!

Comment: GCD is vastly lighter weight than `lock`/`unlock` and traditional across-the-user-kernel-boundary synchronization mechanisms.   I'd recommend diving in fully to GCD and running with it.  Given your background, it shouldn't be too hard and you'll find that it is significantly more efficient (and, IMO, considerably simpler to think "queue" instead of "thread").

Comment: If my superficial (at the time) understanding is that GCD is a thread pooling framework where different tasks a been submitted to different queues that run thread pools behind the scenes. Another interesting observation is that I have been told recently that "long running" threads would abuse GCD and I should use regular NSThread mechanism (see one of the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204001/objective-c-and-arc-object-produced-in-one-thread-does-not-get-released-in-the?noredirect=1#comment24920487_17204001). So, who is right? Is GCD applicable for long running threads?

Comment: In between.   You don't want to schedule a long running task on the global queues.  If you have your own serial queue, you can do pretty much whatever you want (keeping in mind that you'll block said queue with long running tasks).  It is a different mindset.  Ultimately, you don't want any threads that ever block or poll that *don't* do so through queues or `NSRunLoop`.   Assuredly, there are reasons -- OpenGL based portable event/rendering, for example -- where using a traditional threading model are warranted.  But network I/O is *generally* not one of them.

Comment: This is a good rule of thumb and it does make perfect sense to me. However, my long running task is a blocking I/O thread that uses FFmpeg HTTP stream reader and demuxer. It is a plain C library that will take months to port/rewrite in native ObjC... Given this, does my long running thread look more like an NSThread candidate? If so, should I give up GCD semaphores and re-write my queue using POSIX `sem_create` family of calls?

Comment: OK -- I'd keep that code as isolated as possible; rewriting as little as required.   Ideally, you'd use the most naturally fitting API with said library to create the concurrency model you need, then hide the entire thing behind an ObjC API that can be used by your app.   This preserves the portability and concurrency model of the underlying tech, while presenting a "native" API for use by iOS/OSX.  The key is isolation between portable/generic bits vs. your platform specific bits. Or, in other words, maximal encapsulation FTW!

Comment: I believe NSURLConnection has a method for making stream requests asynchronously... perhaps give that a look?